# How to make IntelliJ Run Window tools sidebar dissapear to save space?

Tags: intellij-idea, view, settings, customization, mode

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkB3k.jpg

I'm trying to make this IDE more easy to "perceive" and it would be nice to save vertical space since I want to see both code and terminal at the same sime with biggest area possible. I know I waste space with lines sidebar and other things but let's do one step at a time...

So, do you know how to remove tools sidebard from Run window? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you click the `gear` icon on the right upper corner, you will see `Show toolbar` in the list. You may use it to enable/disable toolbar. The screenshot may explain it better.

[image: Gear]

Comment: Oh my god, you're my hero. I want to believe it's the lang barrier what made this solution invisible to me. Thanks a lot. Sorry, I can't upvote you because I'm still a newbie here.